# Python regex within an F string?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, datetime

Currently I have the following:

```
for child in root:
    if child.attrib['startDateTime'] == fr'2019-11-10T{test_time}:\d{{2}}':
        print('Found')
```

Which isn't working. The goal here is to match the datetime string with my own string where `test_time` is formatted as 'HH:MM', and the seconds digits can be anything from 00 - 60.

Is this the correct approach for a problem like this? Or am I better off converting to datetime objects?

Comment: You need to use `re.match()` rather than `==`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the f-string that's the problem. The `r` prefix on a string doesn't mean "regex", it means "raw" - i.e. backslashes are taken literally. For regex, use the [`re` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). Here's an example using [`Pattern.match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.match):

```
import re

regex = fr'2019-11-10T{test_time}:\d{{2}}'
pattern = re.compile(regex)
for child in root:
    if pattern.match(child.attrib['startDateTime']):
        print('Found')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put a regexp in an f-string, but you need to use the `re` module to match with it, not `==`.

```
if re.match(fr'2019-11-10T{test_time}:\d{{2}}', child.attrib['startDateTime']):
    print('Found')
```